# How to post data using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to map post data to variables

**handy.php**

```
     if($this->input->method() === 'post') {
        $obj = json_decode($this->input->raw_input_stream);
        print_r($this->input->raw_input_stream);
        print_r($obj);
        $name = $obj->name;         
        $mobile  = $obj->mobile;
        $state = $obj->state;
         }
```

My postman response is[image: Postman response]

Comment: I see the error for line 276, but which line is that in the above code?

Comment: @KeithChason  5 th line in the above code

Comment: Okay, we definitely need more context then. I don't see where `$name` is defined.

Comment: I hope handy.php is a controller?

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter If you are sending `xyz = 'some_value'` using post you can set that POST value in variable as

```
$xyz = $this->input->post('xyz');
```

Your code should look like:

```
if($this->input->post()) {
        $name = $this->input->post('name');         
        $mobile  = $this->input->post('mobile');
        $state = $this->input->post('state');
}
```

Assuming that you have sent some data for `name, mobile and state`. You can clear notices at your own.

Comment: Tried,but no response

Comment: in that case print_r($_POST) to make sure you are receiving post data in your function. This is(answer) the right way to capture post data in codeigniter.